# Общее время в online на сайте

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Возник вопрос такого рода, время авторизации хранится в строке `data_aut`, время последнего посещения в строке `date_last`. Мне нужно в таблицу занести сколько всего времени пользователь провел в онлайне на сайте за все время. Ну что то типа: времени в онлайн 0 дней 1 час 25 минут 47 сек.

Сначала были соображения, но как повозился, то голова уже ниче не варит:)
`data_aut`, `date_last` имеют тип int(11) и принимают значение time(); мне же в другую таблицу нужно вынести сколько времени пользователь находился в онлайн, и приплюсовать к тому что уже было ранее, а если не было, занести текущее с последующим обновлением. Строка в таблице, где хранится общее время, имеет имя time с типом int(11). Сначала я подумал вычесть из время провождения, время авторизации, но ничего не получилось...

Я еще новичок, так что не судите строго:) все мы учимся на ошибках.

Comment: а почему бы не создать еще одну ячейку, под время?

Comment: Не вполне вас понял! Даже если и создать,вопрос все равно остается открытым

Answer (score 1):

Сталкивался с уже с рассуждениями на эту тему, скажем так идей очень много для реализации данной задачи, начина от банальных ячеек с переплюсовкой, и кончая созданием отдельной таблицы для ведения статистики посещаемости, времени, даже с отображением всего на графике, в вашем случае мне кажется, можно из времени входа, и времени выхода, высчитать сколько чел провел на сайте времени, проверить при первой записи ячейку на присутствие данных, если нет данных просто записать, а если есть то приплюсовать новое значение к тому что уже в ячейки, думаю что как то так.

Comment: это то я понял, вопрос как высчитать время пребывания на сайте, если у меня и там и там значения принимают time();
например:
   $t=$user[date_last]-$user[data_aut]; // из времени захода вычитаем время авторизации
   а потом это время прибавить к ячейке в которой будет хранится общее время на сайте.
   Но вот вопрос, какой функцией пользоваться чтобы выводилось 
00 дней 00 часов 00 минут 00 сек.
пробовал date(); Но так не получилось...

Comment: помогите плиз....